# How to first use custom script to page load in WordPress theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

How can a custom script be used on a page and along with custom CSS and JavaScript in a WordPress plugin?

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#iview').iView({
                pauseTime: 22000,
                directionNav: false,
                controlNav: true,
                tooltipY: -15
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Clarify your requirement.

Comment: Try referring https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: 37 errors in the console doesn't look promising :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enqueue your scripts before other script loads. You can do it by setting priority to 0 for your hook. For example, do the following:

```
add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_your_scripts', 0 );

function enqueue_your_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'yourscript', 'URL', array( 'jquery' ) );
   //URL of js in which your custom code exist.
}
```

You can set priority of loading script by change number in add_filter,

reference:
[add filter in wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)